# FindRoot, starting values

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a simple system of equations that I am trying to solve numerically,

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
     b1 = 1
     T = 2
     t = .5

FindRoot[{(1 - xbar1) 2 ra1 == n1 - (1 - n1)/T,
ra1 == (pa1^2) (b1^2)/pw,
pw == (1 - xbar1) ra1 - 1,
xbar1 == 1/t  Log[(t n1 + ra1)/ra1],
t[1 - xbar1] + Log[T] - Log[ra1] + Log[t (1 - n1)/(Exp[t] - 1)] == 
 0},
{{n1, .5}, {ra1, .5}, {pa1, .5}, {pw, 1.5}, {xbar1, .5}}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 11]
```

This is the output I get,

```
FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {0.25,0.333333,2.25,-0.31093,0.432752 
+0.5[0.5]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {5} at 
{n1,ra1,pa1,pw,xbar1} = {0.5,0.5,0.5,1.5,0.5}."de here`{n1,ra1,pa1,pw,xbar1} =                    `   {0.5,0.5,0.5,1.5,0.5}."``
```

I am wondering if I am not specifying the initial starting values correctly.  I did this on a similar problem just using NSolve and I had no problem getting a result so I am stumped to what the problem is here.